# I am creating a URL string from a form. How do I encode the URL based off what I have?

Tags: javascript, forms, character-encoding

I have this as my form:

```
    <form method="POST" id="formtwo">
    <p>Agent Name:<br><input type="text" name="agentName" value="Agent Name"></p>
    <p>Agency Name:<br><input type="text" name="agencyName" value="Agency"></p>
    <p>Agent ID:<br><input type="text" name="agentId" value="123455"></p>
    <p>Phone Number:<br><input type="text" name="phoneNo" value="555-555-5555"></p>
    <p>Email:<br><input type="text" name="agentEmail" value="test@hello.com"></p>
    <p>Agent City:<br><input type="text" name="agentEmail" value="test@hello.com"></p>
    <p>Agent State:<br><input type="text" name="agentState" value="Two Letter State Abbreviation"></p>
    <p>Partner Rep<br><input type="text" name="partnerRep" value="Partner Rep"></p>
    <p>Regional Office:<br><input type="text" name="regionalOffice" value="Regional Office"></p>
    <p><input id="submitButton" value="Get Your URL" type="submit"></p>


</form>
```

Then for my javascript to build the URL I am using an alert, but I want to use urlencode on the result. What do I need to change in this JS:

```
$("#formtwo").submit( function() {

    alert( window.location.href + "partner/" + $("input[name=agencyName]").val() + "?agentId=" + $("input[name=agentId]").val() + "&" + "phoneNo=" + $("input[name=phoneNo]").val() + "&" + "agentEmail=" + $("input[name=agentEmail]").val() + "&" + "agentName=" + $("input[name=agentName]").val() );

});
```

This is the jsfiddle that produces the url without encoding.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLmsb1xo/69/)

Comment: You're submitting the form anyway (albeit to the wrong address). So why don't you fix the form instead and let the browser do the work of correctly submitting the values?

Comment: I want the URL to display on page.